# AMSlideMenu overlaps status bar?

Tags: ios, amslidemenu

When displaying the left menu, the scrollview goes under the status bar. 
[image]

I already tried to setContentInset to the tableview. It adds a top margin, but when I scroll it, it overlaps the status bar again.

Any solution for this?

Comment: Set your TableView's y coordinate to 20 pixels
`[myTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-20.0)];`

Comment: thanks for replying, but unfortunately it doesn't work either.. setFrame to my tableview doesn't take any effect..

Comment: Have you put it in a `viewDidLoad` method ?

Comment: yes, also tried in viewWillAppear..

Comment: If you are using xibs or any IB you should call this after the view is loaded from xib

Comment: putting the code inside viewDidAppear works!! thank you very much man!

Answer (score 1):

Putting the code Roma-MT provided:

```
[myTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-20.0)];
```

in viewDidAppear worked!